# Check type of class an NSData store?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

I have a library that process a string and converts it to an unknown format and insert it into a NSData. In a part of the code that library check if the NSData is empty, if not it sends to the server:

```
if (!dataToSend) {
return;
}
```

I thought the stored value would be a string or base64, for that tested the following codes:

```
NSLog(@"To string -> %@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[dataToSend bytes]]);

NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataToSend encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Decode String Value: %@", decodedString);
```

In console I continue receiving `(null)`, but the data is not null once I insert that code below from `return;`. How I can check the type of that NSData stores?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Check the type of NSData
- `if([yourData isKindOfClass: [NSData class]])`