# NSData caching routine

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

I found by accident that i have `NSData` even when i'm not connected by internet. I suppose that there is some caching features. I need to check, if there is data exist, before launch load process. Consider following code:

```
NSError *error;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", WEBSITE, mdl.imageSubUrl]] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];; 
NSLog(@"data size? %lu", (unsigned long)data.length);
```

When i first launch app it output nothing, but when i launch app, close it, then launch again without internet connection, it does output length.

However, i need to check, is there any data "cached" or something before trying to get data by url. Is there any way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think cached data is being returned on the second call.  Have you inspected the data?

Comment: @danh i did not, but i can assure you, that second time i load app (when all images has been loaded), there is data, even when it dataWithContentsOfURL, and url is not availible, of course

Comment: I believe you, but you may only conclude that it is cached data if it matches the result of a prior request.  Log some bytes and see.

Comment: @danh, well, there is a "carousel" of images, so, there is the same correct images when i load app in airplane mode :)

Comment: When you say "close the app" do you mean force-quit it by bringing it up in the task list and flicking up to terminate it?

Comment: @DuncanC yes exactly force quit

Comment: Go to this link: I given my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37091517/check-type-of-class-an-nsdata-store/37091929#37091929