# NSData stored somewhere

Tags: ios, objective-c

recently i created a post: [NSData caching routine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37232480/nsdata-caching-routine)

But, now i want to be more specific in what i'm asking.

You see, i have "carousel", that is actually a scroll view having 7 images. When it first appear, it load images from internet and auto scrolling.

My problem is, i don't want to images be loaded every time it scroll. Luckily, there is some "cache" mechanics worked in background. So, when it load all images, then terminate app, then launch in without internet connection, all images are set already, so, it somehow load it from somewhere.

There is the code i use:

```
NSError *error;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", WEBSITE, mdl.imageSubUrl]] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];;
NSLog(@"data size0? %lu", (unsigned long)data.length);
```

And that is. You may want to try it by yourself, loading some image, then restart app in airplane mode and check bytes length. There will be data, even when i search for it, and there is said, that `dataWithContentsOfURL` does not do any cache.

So, what i want is simply check, if there are data, and if it is, not download it. Something like this:

```
if (haveData){

self.ivPic.image = [UIImage imageWith:myData];

} else {


    NSError *error;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", WEBSITE, mdl.imageSubUrl]] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];;
    NSLog(@"data size0? %lu", (unsigned long)data.length);

}
```

Unfortunately, i don't know how to make such test (if there is data). Secondly, i'm not quite sure how to load stored data, instead of dataWithContentsOfURL, which will launch loading from host.

Comment: You can try UIImageView+AFNetworking.h category of AFNetworking [link](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Categories/UIImageView+AFNetworking.html).
This will solve yout purpose in a way that donot need to handle caching because AFNetworking takes care of it.

Comment: Using `dataWithContentsOfURL` is bad idea (it's synchronous). As others have suggested, third party `UIImageView` categories can do asynchronous requests, but also simplify it for you. Note, AFNetworking's caching relies upon `NSURLCache` behavior, and your headers (or the size of the downloads with respect to the size of the cache) might be preventing caching from taking place. How big are the image files, and how big is your `NSURLCache`?

Comment: @Rob I did call this Block in background thread. If I use other library as you suggest, how can I load saved image instead of downloading new?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban You need not take care of whether to take image from cache or download it again. AFNetworking takes care of it on it's own depending on the image URL.

Comment: @TechGeek_iOS - Agreed, though my point is that if the default `NSURLCache` is too small (or if the image is too big), no caching will take place. AFNetworking relies upon poorly documented caching behavior of `NSURLCache`. Evgeniy, try it, and 99% of the time AFNetworking will be fine. But sometimes it's a pain, either if your assets are too large or if their HTTP headers aren't quite right.

Comment: @Rob you basically said that with single method I will get behavior that I need without any explicitly checking? Sounds great )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to do this yourself, you could create two-tier cache system, using `NSCache` and local file system. So,

1. At app startup, instantiate a `NSCache` object.
2. When you need to download an image, see if image is in `NSCache`.
3. If not, see if image is in `NSCachesDirectory` folder in file system, if found here, but not in `NSCache`, make sure to update `NSCache` accordingly.
4. If found in neither `NSCache` nor `NSCachesDirectory`, request it asynchronously from the network (using `NSURLSession`) and if you successfully found image, update both `NSCache` and `NSCachesDirectory` accordingly.
5. BTW, upon `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification`, make sure to empty the `NSCache`.

That might look something like:

```
NSString *filename = [webURL lastPathComponent];
NSURL *fileURL;

// look in `NSCache`

NSData *data = [self.cache objectForKey:filename];

// if not found, look in `NSCachesDirectory`

if (!data) {
    NSError *error;
    NSURL *cacheFileURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:false error:&error];
    fileURL = [cacheFileURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];

    // if found, update `NSCache`

    if (data) {
        [self.cache setObject:data forKey:filename];
    }
}

// if still not found, retrieve it from the network

if (!data) {
    [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:webURL completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            // handle error
            return;
        }

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

        // if image retrieved successfully, now save it
        if (image) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.cache setObject:data forKey:filename];
                NSError *fileError;
                [data writeToURL:fileURL options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&fileError];
            });
        }
    }];
}
```

Having said all of this, I agree with the others that it's worth trying the `UIImageView` categories found in either [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) and/or [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). They might do what you need, with far less work.

Comment: how exactly should I check if file stored in cache? In my case it is stored somewhere, but I can't figure out where

Comment: Checking if it's in `NSCache`, you'd use `objectForKey`. Checking if it's in `NSCachesDirectory`, you'd use `dataWithContentsOfURL`.

Comment: by the way, if I use sdweb image or afnetwork, it check behind scenes if there are image, and if it is (cached, stored), it load it from disk, but not Internet?

Comment: Yes, they both do caching, too, transparently to you. AFNetworking relies upon `NSURLCache`. SDWebImage has its own `NSCache` and file system caching logic (though I have some faint memory about SDWebImage clearing its file system cache when the app terminates, but I haven't looked at that for quite a time, so you'll have to check it out yourself).

Answer (score 2):

- Firstly you should check the type:
- Got to this link: I given my answer here: [Check type of class an NSData store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37091517/check-type-of-class-an-nsdata-store/37091929#37091929)

  Hope this helps you.